# How do you build a Python library zip file (e.g. Python38.zip) from a source distribution? (e.g. Python-3.8.2.tgz)

Tags: python, module, zip

If you look at most newer pre-made distributions, if contains a zip file (e.g. python38.zip) which contains many library modules and thus makes for a cleaner distribution.  But I can't find any code in the build that actually makes it, and when I run the build, no such file is made.

Update:
I have a partial answer to this.  Tools to zip up files are included with the Python distribution.  Even so, the nominal builds for windows and (presumably) Linux do not produce an executing directory with a python.zip in it.  Not sure what calls to make, or if they can be flagged with the configure.